# Gravitation and revolution

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, reference-frames, orbital-motion

We know that earth and moon attracts themselves towards them in the same force. It is the gravitational force. That's why the moon revolves around earth. But the moon also attracts earth towards itself.And we know, $a=F/m$. So why doesn't earth revolves around the moon?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycenter

Answer (score 0):

You state that $a = F/m$: this is the key to understanding why the moon rather than the Earth moves.

Let's say the force of gravity is $F$, the mass of the Earth is $M_e$ and the mass of the moon is $M_m$.

Now, note that $M_e \gg M_m$ therefore, since $a_e = F/M_e$ and $a_m = F/M_m$, we can flip the inequality to get $a_e \ll a_m$.

This shows that in comparison to the acceleration of the Moon, the acceleration of the Earth is negligible and so the Moon revolves around the Earth rather than the other way around.

---

Note that in systems such as some binary star systems, $M_e \sim M_m$, so the accelerations are similar and they *both* revolve around a point in between the two stars.

Comment: Your answer contained something about binary star system and I didn't quite understood that.

Comment: @AsifIqubal If the masses of the two stars are similar, they will *both* revolve noticebly around each other